# Logs generated by Log4j are not deleted by Yarn

Tags: apache-spark

The `/app-logs/ourUser/logs-ifile` is not cleaned by [YARN](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html), there are many many, now 5668816 log-files (!), including 2-years-old files.

Our Scala Spark source-codes are using the [log4h API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/scala-api.html):

```
import org.apache.log4j._  
val log: Logger = Logger.getLogger(Execute.getClass)
log.info("mensagem")
```

We was supposing that this kind of logs are deleted by YARN in 10 days (our [yarn.log](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) is enabeled and `yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds` set to 10*24*60*60 seconds).